# Probability of catching covid - statistical model

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have been thinking about this approximate model of what is the probability of you catching covid based on the assumption how many people you were in contact with that would transmit it to you, if they were positive. However I am not sure how to calculate the final probability with eg. these numbers:

tot-pop-size = 1700

contact-pop = 490

active-cases = 2

So you are part of society that in total has 1700 people. You were in close contact with some of 490 people that belong to that 1700 group. Within the total population of 1700 there is 2 people that currently have covid.

What is the probability that within your contact group there is at least one person from the group of active cases?

Comment: Can this question really be solved without making some assumptions?

Comment: What type of assumptions for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the contact population is chosen at random from the entire population, the probability of not meeting an active case is $$\frac{1698 \choose 490}{1700 \choose 490},$$ which is slightly above $0.5$. Hence, the probability of meeting at least one sick person is also $0.5$.